# Using Twilio in Node.js,

Tags: node.js

I am trying to make an automated SMS text app using Twilio and I am having a hard time connecting it to my localhost. I keep receiving a "cannot /get" error. Basically, I am trying to send and receive messages using a webhook. Can someone take a look and see what's going on? This code was given to me by Twilio:

```
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const MessagingResponse = require('twilio').twiml.MessagingResponse;

const app = express();


app.post('/sms', (req, res) => {
  const twiml = new MessagingResponse();

  twiml.message('The Robots are coming! Head for the hills!');

  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'});
  res.end(twiml.toString());
});

http.createServer(app).listen(2001, () => {
  console.log('Express server listening on port 2001');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you've misplaced `post` but wanted `get` (since you're trying to access the route via a `get` request)

change

```
app.post('/sms' ...
```

to

```
app.get('/sms' ...
```